# Uploading files with Python to a cloud

Tags: python, python-3.x, cloud

I would like to upload .pdf reports of data, generated in python (on a raspberry pi), onto a cloud that would make the files available through the Internet to other users.

I would like to know what would be the best way to do this. I know that the question is kind of odd, but I have no idea how to establish a direct connection from the point of generating the report, to the web server or cloud, where the data could be collected from...

I've tried using ownCloud, but wasnt able to establish a connection using the pyocclient module. If there is a way to upload files with Python to Google cloud or any other free clouds, I would be glad if anyone could explain me how to do it...

Thank you in advance for any given suggestions,
Regards,

L

Comment: What is “a cloud”? Do you mean a storage service like Dropbox/Google Drive/etc.?

Comment: This question is really to broad to have  definite answer. You need to narrow it down. Are you looking for a specific API?

Comment: requests is probably the answer, even if i cant tell quite what the question is.

Comment: Sorry guys, I agree that I wasnt specific enough, I edited my question but Im really not educated nor experienced in the whole cloud/server area so I am sorry if the question was too broad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever I deal with anything web related (maps, calendar, cloud storage, ect). I look at google first. Google has a wide variety of tools available for developers including one to manage a google drive. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python is a quick start on using python to access the google cloud. It supplies a step by step tutorial on connecting to google. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads gives a set by step guide on uploading a file using a variety of languages (including python). Hope this helps!